# Google Spreadsheet: Compress the content of a cell with GZIP and store it as Base64 value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a few strings in my Spreadsheet which I would like to compress with `GZIP` and store the compressed result as `Base64` value, e.g. the string "This is awesome" in cell `A1` should become "VGhpcyBpcyBvZGVkIHN0cmluZw=="

Is this possible using Google Apps Script or using default Google Spreadsheet functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Utilities class, you can make a "blob" from a string<sup>1</sup>, zip it<sup>2</sup>, and then encode the zip<sup>3</sup>.

<sub>1. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob%28String%29</sub>

<sub>2. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#zip%28BlobSource%29</sub>

<sub>3. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Encode%28Byte%29</sub>

Comment: Thank you, Fred! By the way, is the zipped result compatible with `GZIP`?

Comment: There is also a `gzip` function now: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#gzipblob